# Android - Async validation from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, promise

I am using Parse in order to store my data. During the user 's registration, I create an `AsyncTask` to set the result in the calling activity if the user's email exists or not. Here is the code to trigger the validation

```
View.OnClickListener btnNextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (etEmail == null) {
            return;
        }

        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        if (email == null || email.length() == 0) {
            etEmail.setError(getResources().getString(
                R.string.error_email_is_null)
            );

            etEmail.requestFocus();
            valid = false;
        } else {
            if (!Common.isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
                etEmail.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_email_not_valid));
                etEmail.requestFocus();
                valid = false;
            } else {

                // validate Email from back end
                new CheckEmailAsyncTask(CreateAccountActivity.this, email).execute();

                if (emailValid == false) {
                       etEmail.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_email_existed));
                    etEmail.requestFocus();
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (valid) {
            // if valid then going to the next step
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, UpdateUserActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstant.PARAM_EMAIL, email);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    boolean emailValid;

    public void setEmailValid (boolean emailValid) {
        this.emailValid = emailValid;
    }
};
```

and this is the code for CheckEmailAysncTask

```
public class CheckEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context;
    CreateAccountActivity createAccountActivity;

    String email;

    public CheckEmailAsyncTask(CreateAccountActivity createAccountActivity, String email){
        this.createAccountActivity = createAccountActivity;
        this.context = createAccountActivity;
        this.email = email;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(context);
        try {
            int count = userDAO.isUserExists(email);

            if (count > 0) {
                createAccountActivity.setEmailValid(false);
            } else {
                createAccountActivity.setEmailValid(true);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);


     }
    }
}
```

and in `UserDAO`

```
public int isUserExists(String email) throws ParseException {
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("User");

    query.whereEqualTo("email", email);

    return query.count();
}
```

However, in my setup, the code below the AsyncTask will be executed first before the result are returned back to from Parse. How can I just let the rest of the code wait for future return and then continue ? One of the solution that I come up with is to keep looping the calling to the AsyncTask and sleep for  while until the result is back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I just came up with is sending a callback to the DAO layer function so when the `done` action is triggered, it will trigger back the callback to move on.

```
public interface NavCallback {
    public void finish();
}


public class MainActivity {
    // inside click listener
     NavCallback navCallbackError = new NavCallback() {
     @Override
     public void finish() {
         setError();
     }    
     .....
}
```

and the DAO function will take the callback as the parameters

```
public void checkExists(String email, NavCallback callback) {
    ..... 
    if (callback != null) callback.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (email == null || email.length() == 0) {
    ...
}
else if (email != null & email.length() != 0) {
    ...
}
```